# .NET equivalent functionality for C++ Builder

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, c++builder

I am developing a native application using C++ Builder. I have added an internal browser control (using the supplied TCppWebBrowser class) to the application (a first for me :-)). This control currently uses an external HTML file to start things up. So far, So good...

I have seen a similar application written in VB.NET and there I saw that you could command the browser control (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) to load an internal content (i mean HTML page). It was something like this:

```
theWebBrowser.DocumentText = theStringThatHoldsTheContent
```

Does anybody know TCppWebBrowser class or any queried interface through it has this functionality ? Any URL, InterfaceName, snippet is OK...

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open links from a TCppWebBrowser component in the systems default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558768/how-do-i-open-links-from-a-tcppwebbrowser-component-in-the-systems-default-brows)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Thanks to Remy, I can move on...

Comment: See this related post, It may be useful for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637550/detecting-external-content-with-tembeddedwb-or-twebbrowser/10647630#10647630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate the browser to the "about:blank" URL, wait for the navigation to finish, then you can query the `Document` property for the `IPersistStreamInit` interface and call its `Load()` method. It takes an `IStream` interface as input. You can use the VCL's `TStreamAdapter` class to wrap any VCL `TStream` object, such as a `TMemoryStream` (`TStreamAdapter` implements the `IStream` interface). You can then store your HTML in the `TStream` as needed.